# What is the meaning of this statement in c++?

Tags: c++, string, vector

The statement

```
vector<int>v(string s);
```

and if I print this:

```
cout << v << endl;
```

the result is "1" !!

Comment: That looks like a function prototype for `vector<int> v(string s);` If so, then there's no way to know why you get what you get without seeing its definition.

Comment: Turn up your warning level. I got this with `-Wall -Wextra`: `warning: the address of ‘std::vector<int> v(std::string)’ will always evaluate as ‘true’ [-Waddress]`.

Answer (score 5):

This is a declaration for a function named `v`, that takes a parameter of type `string` and returns a value of type `vector<int>`.

When you print it with `cout<<v`, there is no overload for `operator<<` that takes a pointer to a function of this type, so instead it gets converted to a `bool` with value `true` (as it's non-null), which is printed as `1`.

Comment: hhhhhh right, I can't believe I asked something like that :)
thank you